# Can “möchten” be used with future tense?

Tags: verb, tense

I’ve learnt from grammar books that *möchten* is *mögen* in subjunctive 2. I would like to use it but together with *werden*. Is it possible?

> Ich möchte es lesen.
>
> Ich werde es lesen möchten.

Comment: "werden" + any verb form other than Infinitiv is wrong.

Comment: @Eller So when your boss tells you "Sie werden befördert!", you will respond "please let me correct your grammar"?

Comment: @Eller your statement is correct if we add "in order to conjugate the *Futur I* tense" ... think of the verb tenses from the *Konjunktiv* family and passive speech.

Answer (score 7):

Your grammar book is correct: *möchten* is not a verb of its own right, it is simply an inflected form of *mögen.* Thus, taking it into any case other then present you must use a corresponding form of *mögen:*

> *Ich möchte ein Brot.*
>
> Ich mochte ein Brot.
>
> Ich habe ein Brot gemocht.
>
> Ich werde ein Brot mögen.
>
> Ich werde ein Brot gemocht haben.

However note two things:

1. It is *very* uncommon to use future tense in German in everyday language. In almost all cases, present tense is used instead.

   > Morgen möchte ich ein Brot.
2. Since using the form *möchte* is directly requesting something, it sounds weird to my ears putting it into any other tense. The requesting sense of *möchte* overlaps too strongly with the full verb *mögen* in its *to want* meaning, so I am much more inclined to understand those sentences as ‘I wanted; I will want; I will have wanted’ without the intrinsic politeness of *möchte.*

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, I would argue I am yet more inclined to understand all sentences except the first one in the "to like" meaning of "mögen". Unless it is clear from the context ("Ich mochte ein Brot haben."; "Ich mochte ein Brot, aber er hat mir keines gegeben."), "Ich mochte ein Brot." unequivocally means to me "I liked the taste of the bread."

Comment: So would be some kind of sentence wrong "ich werde ein Brot essen mögen"?

Comment: @Dragut Nope, not wrong. Just unusual as most cases of the *werden* future are somewhat unusual.

Comment: "Ich mag Marzipan" bedeutet, dass ich eine generell libidinös besetze Beziehung zu Marzipan pflege, während "Ich möchte Marzipan" bedeutet, dass es mir aktuell nach Marzipan verlangt. Da ich eben Marzipan hatte möchte ich jetzt keins, aber mögen tue ich Marzipan immer noch, wobei "mögen tun" die Sprache arg strapaziert, aber gängiger Sprachgebrauch ist.

Answer (score 4):

Subjunctive, as described in grammar books is rarely used in everyday-German. Everybody who reads »Ich möchte es lesen« will understand this sentence as indicative in presence tense: A German native speaker understand this sentence as »I (really) want to read it«, not as »I would read it (if something happens)«

To really show the subjunctive use, you have to construct sentences like this:

> Ich möchte es lesen: Wäre das Buch von einem anderen Autor, so möchte ich es lesen.

compare with this similar construction:

> Ich stürbe daran: Wäre ich noch lebendig, so stürbe ich bald durch deines Bogens schnellen Pfeil.

When used in Futur I, you don't decline the full verb, but the auxiliary verb. And even more important: You use the infinite form as full verb, which in the case of »möchten« is »mögen«:

> Indikativ: Morgen werde ich es mögen.
>   Konjunktiv II: Morgen würde ich es mögen.
>
> Indikativ: Morgen werde ich sterben.
>   Konjunktiv II: Morgen würde ich sterben.

Comment: +1 für "stürbe" im Beispiel. Rettet den Konjunktiv!

Comment: Du mäanderst hier ganz schön um eine Antwort herum …

Comment: Wie wäre es mit "ich möchte das Buch lesen wollen"?

Comment: @Beta: Damit wäre es schlecht. "Ich möchte das Buch lesen" drückt bereits den Wunsch aus. "Ich werde das Buch lesen wollen (aber will es noch nicht lesen, weil ich erst den ersten Teil lesen will, und dieses Buch ist Teil 2) oder (aber erst muss ich mein Deutsch verbessern)." Im Extremfall lässt sich aber auch ein entlegener Sinn konstruieren, bei dem man "möchte lesen wollen" sagen könnte, nämlich wenn man es durchaus lesen könnte, aber nicht wollen kann aber gerne wollen könnte würden.

Answer (score 3):

As you write,

> Ich möchte.

is Konjunktiv 2 of

> Ich mag.

It is often used as a more polite substitute for

> Ich will.

In that case it will be perceived as a verb of its own in Indikitav Präsens (like *will*) by many speakers. However this verb (which, as we just saw, does not really exist) is lacking any forms that are not Indikativ Präsens, in particular it has no infinitive *möchten*. (I remember that this has been discussed here before, with not everyone agreeing to which extent this is still true for colloquial German.) Since it has no infinitive, you cannot use it in Futur, and you will have to replace it with another verb, such as *wollen*.

> Ich werde es lesen **wollen.**

In most cases it will not be necessary to modify this to make it more polite, since a future desire is less likely to be interpreted as a demand than a present one. On the other hand, it may also be possible to just leave it as

> Ich möchte es lesen.

since this already expresses your wish for a future action, and you can modify it by adding when you would like to read it.

> Ich möchte es **nächstes Jahr** lesen.

This would only be wrong if you currently do not feel inclined to read it later but expect to develop a desire to read it at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

No. This doesn't work, as *werden* can't govern *Konjunktiv II*. Actually, no auxiliary verb can govern *Konjunktiv II*, instead, any auxiliary verb will be put into *Konjunktiv II* instead. So it should be:

1. Ich möchte das Buch
2. Ich würde das Buch mögen

However, two things have to be taken into account: *würde* may have temporal meaning in some cases, but often it is just used as an analytical replacement for synthetic *Konjunktiv II*. Apart from that, *möchten* is not understood as *Konjunktiv II* of *mögen* anymore. So (2) is neither (1) in the future or identical to (1) in terms of *Konjunktiv II*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with

> Ich werde es lesen mögen.

other than that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. This would imply that you don't want to read it at the moment but you know you will want to read it in the future. Grammatically correct though.